# JSONP with ISBNdb

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, jsonp

I am trying to pull in book data upon a user form submission from the [ISBNdb API](http://isbndb.com/api/v2/docs). I am using JSON in the url as required. As of now I am using the form to search by [books category](http://isbndb.com/api/v2/docs/books) (see about halfway down page). When I enter a search term, I get 2 errors in the console:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   text/plain:
>   "http://isbndb.com/api/v2/json/J6FR9HT6/books?jsoncallback=jQuery1111037271023145876825_1404698815454&q=science&_=1404698815455".
>
> jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I see the `q=science` that I am expecting, but what is all the other stuff jQuery seems to be adding? Any help MUCH appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

 $('form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchTerm = $('#search').val();
    // the AJAX part
    var isbndbAPI = 'http://isbndb.com/api/v2/json/J6FR9HT6/books?jsoncallback=?';

    var bookOptions = {
      q: searchTerm
    };
    function displayBookData(data) {
      var bookHTML = '<ul>';
      $.each(data.data,function(i,book) {           
        bookHTML += '<li>';
        bookHTML += book.title;
        bookHTML += '</li>';
      }); // end each
      bookHTML += '</ul>';
      $('#book-results').html(bookHTML);
    }
    $.getJSON(isbndbAPI, bookOptions, displayBookData);

  }); // end submit

}); // end ready

</script>

</head>
<body>


<form>
  <label for="search">Type a search term</label>
  <input type="search" name="search" id="search">
  <input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit">
</form>

<div id="book-results"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE

It seems to receive the JSON back okay, and I can see the results in the console. Still confused as this is all new to me. Also, I may not be displaying it as HTML correctly either.

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fisbndb.com%2Fapi%2Fv2%2Fjson%2FJ6FR9HT6%2Fbooks%3Fq%3Dscience%22&format=json&callback=mycallback

Comment: @ansarob See post, https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/ . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `url` at original post did not include a parameter required by the api :

`error: "'query' or 'q' is a required parameter"`

See [ISBNdb API -- Version 2](http://isbndb.com/api/v2/docs)

> Request URL: http://isbndb.com/api/v2/xml/mykey/books**?q=science**

Try

```
$.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select"
          +"* from json where url='http://isbndb.com/api/v2/json/J6FR9HT6/books?q=science'"        
          +"&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?"
          , function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
              console.log(data.query.results.json.data);
              $.each(data.query.results.json.data, function(index, value) {
                  $("<li>", {"text" : value.title +", " 
                            + (value.author_data 
                              ? (value.author_data.name 
                                ? value.author_data.name 
                                : value.author_data.id) 
                              : void(0)) }).appendTo("ul");                  
              });              
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/bZBLf/

Comment: can you explain `https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select` this part? why do we need to query it through yahooapis.com ?

Comment: @Shri `$.get("http://isbndb.com/api/v2/xml/mykey/books?q=science") // XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://isbndb.com/api/v2/xml/mykey/books?q=science&_=1452400793835. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 0):

The API you mentioned does not support JSONP. As its [documentation](http://isbndb.com/api/v2/docs) states, it only supports JSON, YAML, and XML.

> ### Response Formats
>
> The API will serialize it's return data in one of 3 different formats:
>
> **Json** - /api/v2/json/my-api-key
> **Yaml** - /api/v2/yaml/my-api-key
> **XML** - /api/v2/xml/my-api-key

jQuery tries to treat the returned JSON file as a JS file, but it isn't thus causing the error.

Comment: So how am I supposed to pull in the data if I can't use JSONP?

Comment: @ansarob - You can use the [jQuery cross-domain plugin](https://github.com/padolsey/jquery.fn/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax) to work around the Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 0):

Your server-side either needs to change its content-type to give you JSON, or you need to get the data back and treat it as text, then convert to JSON.

It looks like you are trying to request JSONP though ... not sure if you can/how easy it will be to pull it down as text and then convert it and still get the callback to run.